# AngularJS search filter in array into object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I look ID in an array of objects JSON.
Example JSON:

```
{
    "Przydzial": [{
            "M": "Cos",
            "Przydzialt": [{
                    "Name": "",
                    "Przydz": "tach_1",
                    "Cos": "Pod",
                    "Ha": "20",
                    "ID": "94"
                }, {
                    "Name": "B_K",
                    "Przydz": "lea",
                    "Cos": "Chea",
                    "HA": "8",
                    "ID": "78"
                }
            }]
    }]
}
```

Use in controller

```
var foo = { //my json };
var nowy = $filter('filter')(foo.Przydzialt, { ID:78});
```

result:

```
console.log(nowy); // undefined
```

json is correct - validated in JSLint.

Comment: The example JSON is invalid. Extra `}`.

Comment: Sorry is foo not $too - json is example

Comment: Do not use polish variable names in the code

Comment: Try `($foo.Przydzialt, { ID:'78'});`. like in your object `"ID": "78"`.

Answer (score 1):

As "$foo.Przydzial" is an array of objects, where every object has its "Przydzialt" attribute, you should execute $filter in a loop:

```
var newArray;

angular.forEach($foo.Przydzial, function (el) {
    newArray = $filter('filter')(el.Przydzialt, {ID: 78});
    console.log(newArray);
});
```

Comment: It is ok only the result of good object and returns an empty array Array [ Object ]
Array [  ]

Comment: Is ok -  if (newArray.length>0) 
solved the problem.Thank you